# How to run same Python script two times simultaneously in two different instances?

Tags: python, spyder, multiple-instances

I want to know that is it possible to run the same script say ABC.py, in two different spyder instances by passing different input values? I know that we can run completely independent projects in multiple spyder instances using `spyder --new-instance`. But, can we use the same approach when we want to run the same project with different input values in two instances?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't understand what you exactly by this. How are you passing input values to your script?

Comment: I have 10 different types of inputs saved in 10 different excel sheets. Currently, while running the script, I am selecting a perticular excel sheet, reading the input values, and passing them to the desired functions. In the second run, I am selecting another excel sheet and so on. This is a sequestial process. I want to open my script in 10 spyder instances to read all the 10 excel sheets, respectively. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder doesn't have a way to be run programmatically in the way you want.

Instead, I recommend you need to create another Python program to run your current script in parallel. For that, you can take a look at [Dask](https://dask.org/).